# How to compare list of strings and list of objects which have one of the data member same as first list

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have `User` class and in that data members are

```
public string userid {get;set;}
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName  {get;set;}
public string address {get;set;}
public string mobilenumber {get;set;}
```

I have another list of string which contain only `userid` in form of string.

**I want to compare `userid` of first list with the string in the second list**

What is the LINQ query for that?

If the `userid` did not match with the string then query should return object present in that list.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you have defined these properties. It makes it easier to give you an exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you have a `List<User>` called Users and a `List<string>` called listOfUserIds. Then you can use the following Linq query to get all the Users who's Ids do not exist in listOfUserIds.

```
Users.Where(user => !listOfUserIds.Any(id => id == user.userid));
```